# NoSuchMethodError: io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setUsePathBasedConfig(Z)V

Tags: java, spring, swagger, cxf

I am working with CXF 3.1.8,i want to integrate Swagger,so i added the code below:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
           <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And in JAXRSServerFactoryBean i added :

```
    JAXRSServerFactoryBean jfb =new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    Swagger2Feature feature=new Swagger2Feature();
   jfb.getFeatures().add(feature);
```

But i get error when i want to deploy my application:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.setUsePathBasedConfig(Z)V
```

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of the swagger-jaxrs dependency that you are using.

I suggest to upgrade the CXF version too. Latest 3.1.x would be 3.1.18, but you should probably use the latest 3.3.0 version. Look here https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/cxf-3.3.0/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs for several working samples.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis for your response.when use the latest version of CXF 3.3.0,an other error was appear is : Missing artifact net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.6. the version wich i use currently is net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.2.0

Comment: It's available on central: http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/2.10.6/

Comment: Although this error seems not to be CXF related, I can take a look, if you provide a sample project.